# How to add items to dropup html/css using java

Tags: java, html, css

I have images that, when you hover over them, a dropup appears. I want to add a button to the bottom of the website that adds a user input item to the dropup.

I have tried using addTo but I can't figure out how to use it with a drop up.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>

    .dropup-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      min-width: 160px;
      bottom: 50px;
      z-index: 1;
      height: 132px;
      overflow: auto;
    }

    .dropup-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }

    .dropup:hover .dropup-content {
      display: block;
    }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="dropup">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5mXfwr1.jpg">
      <div class="dropup-content">
        <a href="http://www.echoecho.com/htmltext03.htm"target="_blank">PF thing 1</a>
        <a href="#">PF thing 2</a>
        <a href="#">PF thing 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>    
    </html>
```

I based my code of of [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropup.asp). It works as intended but I need to modify it so that you can add items on a button click.

Comment: You are describing functionality that only javascript will help with, not a CSS solution.

Comment: What's `addTo`?